# Error when trying to add data to table on Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I made the most simple example, and still I get console error:

```
<div id="testTable"></div>

<script>
    var tableData = [
        {id:1, fullName:"Billy Bob"},
        {id:2, fullName:"Mary May"}
    ];
    var tableData2 = [
        {id:3, fullName:"Bill Gates"},
        {id:4, fullName:"Mr. Jones"}
    ];

    let logsTable = new Tabulator("#testTable", {
        data: tableData,
        columns:[
            {title: "ID", field: "id"},
            {title: "Full Name", field: "fullName"}
            ]
    });

    logsTable.addData(tableData2);

</script>
```

and the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logsTable.on("tableBuilt", function(data){
    logsTable.addData(tableData2);
});
```